# I can't connect via SSH to hosts outside of localhost

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I can connect to hosts within the local network 192.168.1.1/24

I am using plugin "Remote - SSH Microsoft v0.56.0"

When I want to connect to let's say "host.juzek.com" I have logs ↓

```
[17:52:06.274] Log Level: 2
[17:52:06.275] remote-ssh@0.56.0
[17:52:06.275] linux x64
[17:52:06.276] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+bwi1.nazwa.pl", attempt 1
[17:52:06.277] SSH Resolver called for host: bwi1.nazwa.pl
[17:52:06.277] Setting up SSH remote "bwi1.nazwa.pl"
[17:52:06.280] Acquiring local install lock: /tmp/vscode-remote-ssh-bwi1.nazwa.pl-install.lock
[17:52:06.288] Looking for existing server data file at /home/tom/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-bwi1.nazwa.pl-e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f-0.56.0/data.json
[17:52:06.288] Using commit id "e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f" and quality "stable" for server
[17:52:06.290] Install and start server if needed
[17:52:06.293] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[17:52:06.312] > OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020

[17:52:06.315] askpass server listening on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-0cd16048fe996bc94ccca902cb4cdb91239492b4.sock
[17:52:06.315] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-7219cd4427e5f8c4f00bb679602dbeb56a0c9418.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","32895","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","bwi1.nazwa.pl"],"dataFilePath":"/home/tom/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-bwi1.nazwa.pl-e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f-0.56.0/data.json"}
[17:52:06.315] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/opt/visual-studio-code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-0cd16048fe996bc94ccca902cb4cdb91239492b4.sock"}
[17:52:06.319] Spawned 174194
[17:52:06.395] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 174202
[17:52:06.398] stderr> OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
[17:52:06.472] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:nfa6DSkaZotWLQ1kHUBYzUmZ5sXY7OF7I3Soa7tpP5E
[17:52:06.687] Got askpass request: {"request":"bwi1@bwi1.nazwa.pl's password:"}
[17:52:06.688] Showing password prompt
[17:52:06.689] Listening for interwindow password on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-0b05c4333e853dfe4aa21f12df4a12eccfc3097b.sock
[17:52:06.689] Writing password prompt to globalState
[17:52:21.739] Got password response
[17:52:21.739] Interactor gave response: ***************
[17:52:21.741] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[17:52:21.837] stderr> Authenticated to bwi1.nazwa.pl ([85.128.187.234]:22).
[17:52:21.885] > ready: e17070106944
[17:52:21.898] > Linux 4.15.0-112-generic #113~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 04:37:08 UTC 2020
[17:52:21.899] Platform: linux
[17:52:21.914] > e17070106944: running
[17:52:21.965] > Acquiring lock on /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/vscode-remote-lock.bwi1.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
[17:52:21.967] > Installing to /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f...
> e17070106944%%1%%
> Downloading with wget
[17:52:26.570] > Download complete
> e17070106944%%2%%
> tar --version:
[17:52:26.572] > tar (GNU tar) 1.28
> Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
> 
> Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
[17:52:35.729] > Checking /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.log and /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.pid for a running server
[17:52:35.730] stderr> Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc
[17:52:35.732] > Starting server with command... /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/server.sh --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown  --port=0 &> "/home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SSH_CLIENT=83.24.229.64 46822 22
>     LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8
>     USER=bwi1
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>     PWD=/home/bwi1/ftp
>     LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
>     HOME=/home/bwi1/ftp
>     SHLVL=2
>     LOGNAME=bwi1
>     SERVER_ADDR=85.128.187.234
>     SSH_CONNECTION=83.24.229.64 46822 85.128.187.234 22
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
>     OLDPWD=/home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
[17:52:35.736] > Spawned remote server: 222
[17:52:35.738] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:36.240] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:36.742] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:37.244] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:37.747] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:38.246] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:38.749] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:39.251] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:39.753] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:40.255] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:40.757] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:41.259] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:41.761] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:42.263] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:42.763] > Waiting for server log...
[17:52:43.266] >  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
>  
[17:52:43.267] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.log >>>
> node: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:556: uv__close_nocheckstdio: Assertion `fd > -1' failed.
> /home/bwi1/ftp/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/server.sh: line 12:   230 Aborted                 "$ROOT/node" ${INSPECT:-} "$ROOT/out/vs/server/main.js" "$@"
> <<< End of server log
> e17070106944: start
> exitCode==32==
> sshAuthSock====
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> webUiAccessToken====
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> e17070106944: end
[17:52:43.268] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
sshAuthSock====
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
webUiAccessToken====
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==

[17:52:43.270] Terminating local server
[17:52:43.296] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at Function.ServerInstallError (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:1:94355)
    at /home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:1:92571
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:1:93073)
    at Object.t.tryInstallWithLocalServer (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:102430)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async /home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:104510
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:110096)
    at async /home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:101003
    at async R (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:97793)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:100652)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:108038)
    at async /home/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0/out/extension.js:127:143767
[17:52:43.299] Local server exit: 15
[17:52:43.305] -----
```

The authentication details are correct and so is the password. Where did I go wrong?

My VCS
Version: 1.51.1
Commit: e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
Date: 2020-11-10T23:31:29.624Z
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.9.8-arch1-1

Answer (score 0):

As with this [similar thread](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/16688/) (with the same "`Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc`" and  `Assertion` fd > -1' failed.`) the issue could be on the server side.

More specifically, that server might not have all the [Remote host / container / WSL Linux prerequisites](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux) for VSCode to successfully install and run its agent.